# get teachers where exists in 1st and 2nd semesters

Tags: mysql, grouping

```
  ID |user_ID | User_name | semester |
   1 |1       | John      | 1        |
   2 |1       | John      | 2        |
   3 |2       | Ali       | 2        |
```

must return john 
because he exists in 1st and 2nd

I tried with this 
select User_name from teachers where semester in(1,2); 
but it returns john and ali

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: i tried with this select User_name from teachers where semester in('1st','2st'); but its return john and ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want teachers that taught in both semesters, you're query won't work.  It just checks one row at a time.  But, a simple modification gets what you want:

```
select User_name
from teachers
where semester in ('1st', '2st')
group by User_name
having min(semester) <> max(semester);
```

By the way, in English, we use "first" and "second".  These would be abbreviated as "1st" and "2nd".